# How to determine ScalaJS filename for scoped Javascript dependencies

Tags: scala.js

I'm trying to import angular 2 packages as external dependencies to a ScalaJS project.

For example, the `core` dep is referenced as `@angular/core`, and is available on WebJars at `"org.webjars.npm" % "angular__core" "2.0.0-rc.6"`.

When importing in ScalaJS, however, when using this declaration:

```
jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__core" % ngVersion / "angular__core.js"
```

I receive the following error:

```
[error] (compile:resolvedJSDependencies) org.scalajs.core.tools.jsdep.JSLibResolveException: Some references to JS libraries could not be resolved:
[error] - Missing JS library: angular__core.js
[error]   originating from: root:compile
```

I have determined that the problem is related to the `angular__core.js` declaration; changing `"jquery.js"` in `"org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.10.2" / "jquery.js"` replicated the error.

How then, should I name the angular dependency? The [documentation](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html) is not very specific, saying "[the name declaration] include[s] a file ... in the said WebJar when your project is run or tested."

I've tried the following names:

- Angular.js
- @angular/core.js
- angular-core.js
- angular.core.js
- angular_core.js
- angular__core.js

Comment: It is the name of the .js file found *in the jar*. Look at the content of the webjar to determine what is the proper file name to use.

Comment: Thanks! I see I misread the documentation. This library works with "core.umd.js" as the entry point. Your comment should be this question's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the name of the .js file found *in the jar*. Look at the content of the webjar to determine what is the proper file name to use.